# jQuery: mysterious Json parsing error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I am getting an error on a page with a code that works perfectly on another page... Here it is:

```
$.each(json,function(index,element){
var tr = $("<tr>").appendTo($tabbody);
$(tr).append('<td><a target="_blank" href="forum.php?t='+element.topic_id+'">'+element.topic_nom+"</a></td>"+'<td>'+element.date_heure+"</td>");
});
```

json is the result of a GET request on a php page:

```
$data = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($data);
```

An exemple of result:

```
[
    {
    "topic_nom": "Deuxième question de linterro manip 5",
    "topic_id": "1",
    "user_nick": "Symael",
    "user_id": "1",
    "msg_id": "10",
    "date_heure": "2013-02-17 18:28:04"
    },
    {
    "topic_nom": "Quel est le sens de la vie ?",
    "topic_id": "2",
    "user_nick": "Symael",
    "user_id": "1",
    "msg_id": "10",
    "date_heure": "2013-02-17 18:28:04"
    }
]
```

Which is valid Json... The error I get is:

```
TypeError: invalid 'in' operand e
...ute(i),"string"==typeof r){try{r="true"===r?!0:"false"===r?!1:"null"===r?null:+r...
```

And if I try $.parseJSON(json); :

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
...ute(i),"string"==typeof r){try{r="true"===r?!0:"false"===r?!1:"null"===r?null:+r...
```

When I validate my Json on http://jsonlint.com/ the result is:

```
Parse error on line 1:
[    {        "to
^
Expecting '{', '['
```

And if a manually rewrite the first [ it suddenly becomes valid.
I think I'm the victim of a very strange glitch here, could anyone help me ? Oo

---

Here is the solution, see Stoive's answer for explanations.

```
  obj = $.parseJSON(json.trim());
    $.each(obj,function(index,element){
      var tr = $("<tr>").appendTo($tabbody);
      $(tr).append('<td><a target="_blank" href="forum.php?t='+element.topic_id+'">'+element.topic_nom+"</a></td>"+'<td>'+element.date_heure+"</td>");
    });
```

Comment: "Valid JSON" said jsonlint to me.

Comment: You probably have some invisible characters before your data

Comment: It's valid "Valid JSON"

Comment: Yeah because I copied this one from JSONLint after replacing the first bracket...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite often, the [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) can sneak into files saved in editors such as Notepad.

Try fetching the character code of `json` at position 0 and `console.log` the result:

```
console.log(json.charCodeAt(0).toString(16));
```

You should be getting `5b` as the result, and not something like `feff`. If that's the case, then `JSON.parse(json.trim())` could help by removing the invisible whitespace characters.

Comment: "getCharCodeAt is not a function" ? ^^
But $.parseJSON(json.trim()) works !
Thanks a lot, I wouldn't have found it Oo

Comment: And should I chose "UTF-8 (without BOM)" encoding for all my php files then ?

Comment: No problems! My bad, it's `charCodeAt`, now corrected. UTF-8 without BOM is the correct character encoding for a JSON file. I'm not familiar with PHP, so you'd have to check whether it writes a BOM when creating a JSON string.

Comment: The same problem happens when I save the file with a UTF-8 without BOM encoding. Very strange. I've found some PHP scripts that aim to remove the BOM but I'll stick with the javascript solution which is very elegant :)
http://blog.philipp-michels.de/?p=32