# Why always jQuery Ajax JSON Request Fails?

Tags: php, ajax, json, jquery

I currently have a code snippet which I'd like to use to get Ajax Calls and return JSON data from my PHP file which I can use however I want in the jQuery side. My problem is that IF I change the data type to JSON, I always get error on the request, HOWEVER when I inspect it in Firebug I can see that the PHP file has just returned the JSON values fine!

This is the HTML:

```
<form id="formm" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="test" value="" id="test"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<div id="result"></div>
```

This is the JS:

```
$("#formm").submit(function(event) {

    /* Stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault();

    /* Clear result div*/
    $("#result").html('');

    /* Get some values from elements on the page: */
    var values = $(this).serialize();

    /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
    $.ajax({
        url: "functions.php",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: values,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("failure");
            $("#result").html('There is error while submit');
        }
    });
});
```

PHP file:

```
echo json_encode(array('returned_val' => $_POST['test']));
```

When I inspect with Firebug I get: returned_val   "whatever I type in the textbox". Can anyone tell me what could be the problem?

UPDATE:

Response Headers:

```
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language ***
Content-Length  5
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
Host    localhost
Referer http://localhost/test/
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

When I put the errors in the console, I get this:

> The following error occured: parsererror SyntaxError: JSON.parse:
>   unexpected character

Comment: Can you post the response headers?

Comment: Just updated the post.

Comment: shouldn't you serialize JSON string with `JSON.stringify()` instead of serializing it with jquery function `serialize()`?

Comment: Write the json your php file generates to a file and copy/paste it to http://jsonlint.com/ . It will tell you where the problem is. If I have to guess there is a BOM character at the very beginning of your json response.

Comment: @Sumurai8 I have pasted it, and it says the following: Parse error on line 1:
{    "returned_val
^
Expecting '{', '['

So I guess it is using the wrong symbols but why? What did I do that it uses this symbol instead of the good one?

Comment: Can you paste the JSON returned by the server too?

Comment: JSON value, form the PHP: `{"returned_val":"ok"}`

Comment: I suppose that the ^ points before or at the first {. Open the file that server your json and save it as utf-8, but turn off the BOM (byte-order mark). Google a bit if you don't know how to do this for your favourite editor. This should fix the problem. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: mysterious Json parsing error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927800/jquery-mysterious-json-parsing-error)

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working now perfectly :) If you make a new answer I will accept it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected; the server should return a response of null or {} instead

here is the documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

so check your json response from php (whether the json data is well formed and non empty)